# How to redirect to a URL getting from query parameter...?

Tags: java, html

As I'm a beginner in Java, can somebody help me with this query?

My original URL is www.Google.com. I want to add one more URL www.yahoo.com with this URL as a query parameter like "end-URL="

As soon as I will finish my work in www.Google.com, it should redirect to www.yahoo.com...is this possible?

I'm thinking i can use like:

```
<%
response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
%>
```

But I am not sure of this, as I have never used. 
Please help me
Thanks in adv

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have mentioned you are doing correct, incase you want control to be send to other resource you use sendRedirect, if the resource sits on the same server you use forward.

I would suggest reading more at following URL, it has some examples as well for both forward and redirect

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=181

Cheers !!

Comment: Thnx for your response. But my doubt is if the url is coming from the other application, how can i store the value of the target uRL in a session.